# Getting input from user form - simple storage of strings

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, dapps, storage

I am new to the solidity/dapp game, but I'm learning.

Here is some super simple code for a smart contract that I'd like to use to store user input strings from a webform and store those responses on the blockchain so they can be queried later:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract simpleStorage {
string name;
string email;

function simpleStorage() public {
   name = "Hello";
   email = "hi@gmail.com";
}

function setInfo(string userName, string userEmail) public {
    name = userName;
    email = userEmail;
}

function getInfo() constant returns (string, string){
    return (name, email);
}
}
```

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to a) accept string user input, convert to JS/JSON readable format with double quotes and b) set up the web form to work with this contract and my private geth network

Comment: what is your question? have to be more specific

Comment: How do I go about accepting user entry and feeding it into this smart contract?

Comment: I also don't know how exactly the connectors to a webform work

Answer (score 1):

Building a webform is out-of-scope for this community, just too many frameworks to choose from. But for the **contract integration**, I'd recommend you use the [**Web3 JavaScript API**](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to interact with the Ethereum network, which seems to be the most popular at the moment.

Another really great client library is [**Ethers.js**](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js), with amazing documentation found [**here**](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/).

Once you figure it out, interacting with your contracts becomes trivial.

---

It's worth mentioning that when implemented on the **client-side** *(that is in the web browser)*, the burden is then on the user to execute these contracts using their Dapp browser ***(Mist or MetaMask)***. If you want this all to run behind the scenes *(without the user having to know anything about Ethereum or blockchain)*, then each of the aforementioned libraries also have their Node.js counterparts, which can then be **tied to your server's own ethereum wallet.**